# IIS authenticated SOAP Webservice

Tags: c, web-services, iis

How can I authenticate to a web service hosted in IIS that is secured with Integrated Windows Authentication?

Do I use HTTP headers to add username and pwd?

I am trying to call this web service from UNIX in C.

Comment: how exactly? are you using gsoap? are you crafting the message yourself?

Comment: yes. i am creating the soap request myself.

Comment: reading about IWA on wikipedia, I suspect it would be a little bit harder than just adding some headers in the http request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm rather a newbie to IIS myself, and I'm just starting to dance around this topic, but I saw your note and thought it was crazy that no one has answered in so long!

I believe that the typical way that windows authenticates is Kerberos.  You may have to go through some gyrations to get the Windows Kerberos server to get you a ticket that you could put in the SOAP header.  That is at least the direction in which I would start researching... but it could heavily depend on your Windows domain configuration.  At the very least, you'll probably need to do quite a bit of poking into Windows Domain configurations and concepts.